# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Imagick::readimage(): Connection timed out'

Tags: php, imagick

how to fix this error, Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Imagick::readimage(): Connection timed out'...please help me...

```
<?php 
 $image = new Imagick(); 
 $image->readImage($img_url_images); 
 $image->resizeImage(215,190,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1); 
 $thumbnail = $image->getImageBlob();
 ?>

 <img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($thumbnail); ?>" onerror="this.src='Make_In_India.png'">
```

Comment: What is `$img_url_images`? I assume an URL? I guess PHP can't connect to that, which is what the error says: `Connection timed out`.

Comment: $img_url_images = "http://www.hindugodwallpaper.com/images/gods/midsizethumb/632_mahabharat-wallpaper-10.jpg";

Comment: Does that URL load in your browser? It doesn't in mine. So why would you expect it to load in your PHP code?

Comment: sorry i cannot understand...